# Lowering memory usage for PHP script?

Tags: php

So I'm getting data from an API endpoint and adding it to the end of a CSV file that I already have then re-writing the CSV (This is required as I will need logs later down the road for each endpoint I pull from).

I'm new to PHP and not quite sure on the best way to lower memory usage. I've looked around but nothing quite stood out to me.

In my specific example below I have about 100,000 rows in the CSV file.

In order of the memory_get_usage when running the script I got 58982400, 103546880, 103546880. I would like to lower the memory used. Are there any tips or things to keep my eye out for when trying to lower memory used? It looks like 1/2 of the memory is being used getting the data from the endpoint, I assume there isn't much I can do about that usage?

The data from the CSV is basically

```
PersonId,FirstName,LastName,Gender
```

While the data from the endpoint is

```
PersonId,EmailAddress
```

Here is my script.

```
<?php
include('ApiClient.include.php');
$urlStudents = "http://localhost/jsonyes.json";
$crl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $urlStudents);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$execCrl = curl_exec($crl);
$emails = json_decode($execCrl, true);
curl_close($crl);
$fp = fopen('turkeytest.csv', 'r');
$output = fopen("$emailFile", 'w');
$max = 0;
echo "Using GetUse ", memory_get_usage(True), " bytes of ram.";

foreach($emails as $email){
    if(!isset($eData[$email['PersonId']])){
        $eData[$email['PersonId']][] = $email['EmailAddress'];
    } else{
        $eData[$email['PersonId']][] = $email['EmailAddress'];
    }
    if(count($eData[$email['PersonId']]) > $max){
        $max = count($eData[$email['PersonId']]);
    }
} 
echo "Using GetUse ", memory_get_usage(True), " bytes of ram.";

while($row = fgetcsv($fp, ",")){
    $count = count($row);
    if(isset($eData[$row[0]])){
        foreach($eData[$row[0]] as $key => $value){
            $row[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $row = array_pad($row, $max+$count, '');
    fputcsv($output, $row); //writes array $datas to $output file
}
fclose($fp);
echo "Using GetUse ", memory_get_usage(True), " bytes of ram.";
?>
```